# permutation/combination

Tags: permutations, combinations

There are six cards with numbers written on them: $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ .
Two of them are drawn at at time and put together to form fractions, e.g. $\dfrac45$
How many proper fractions can be formed?

What is correct equation to solve this type of questions?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by perfect fractions.

Comment: Are we supposed to take into account whether fractions are in simplest form?  Observe that $1/2 = 2/4 = 3/6$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total ways are 6P2=30. So for a perfect fraction we need  numerator< denominator so 6 cannot be numerator so 5 possibilities are directly eliminated . Now note the order for 6 we have 0 possibilties for 5 1 for 4 2 possibilities till for 1 we have 5 possiblities so answer is $0+1+2+3+4+5=15$ thats the answer to your question there are 15 perfect fractions.

Comment: thanks for this clear explanation!

Comment: @bogumbiker your welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you think of all the possible fractions, exactly half of them will be proper (since you're always drawing cards of two different values), so there are $6 \times 5 \times \frac12$ possibilities.

Comment: @ Eric that turns out to be $7.5$ how can the possibilities be fractional.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Whoops!